# Wordpress Images seem to upload, but don't actually upload

Tags: wordpress, file-upload, image-uploading

On a clean WordPress install, with a fresh download of the latest version of WordPress, I'm having an issue uploading images... but it's not the problem I usually run into.

Here's the problem: **WordPress let's me upload an image, and will save it into the list of media and allow me to give it a title, etc, but the actual file is never uploaded. You can't view it anywhere.** Copying the full path to the image into the address bar also shows that no file is there. When I use FTP to check out the uploads folder, it's empty. I checked other directories to see if for some reason the image was uploaded to the wrong place, but it is nowhere on the server. In WordPress, if I click the "Edit Image" button this message appears: "Image data does not exist. Please re-upload the image."

wp-content is currently set to 767. Usually I can set wp-content to 767, upload the first image so that WP has permission to write in the uploads folder, and then change wp-content back to 755. Usually it works. This is the first time I've run into this specific issue, though.

In WordPress settings I have "Store uploads in this folder" and "Full URL path to files" left blank, however I have tried to type in the proper paths and still couldn't get it working.

I can't find a solution to this anywhere, and would appreciate some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of change the permission to the wp_content folder, try changing the permissioni of the wp-content/upload/ folder.

Also see if there are any issues in the error_log as well.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! I don't know why I didn't think to check the error_log before. Turns out I had PHP Safe Mode enabled for the domain, and that was the cause of my problems. Thanks again!